# how to check if a SSL certificate is corrupt or not?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have a SSL certificate. I want to check if the certificate is intact or corrupted. Are there any tool to check this?

Problem is we are unable to get this certificate working in Websphere 8.0 and I was thinking if this cert file could be corrupted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can check a certificate with openssl (available for windows and *nix).

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

[Reference](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)

**Update**

To be more precise, you can compare the modulus and public exponent of the key and certificate respectively to guarantee that certificate matches the key and that the certificate has not been corrupted.

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key.pem | openssl sha1;\
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt | openssl sha1
```

Valid output would look like

```
7298b69426656f7a8ab3ef9686bc0a79588850e7
7298b69426656f7a8ab3ef9686bc0a79588850e7
```

After hand modifying the cert the output would be.

```
7298b69426656f7a8ab3ef9686bc0a79588850e7
bd439a18d2d3689470e209dbd45b85a41db7230c
```

The command

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

is used for verifying certificate chains but not checking for corruption. A hand modified certificate could return valid looking output but a problem with the `RSA Public Key: (4096 bit) Modulus (4096 bit):` part would only be detectable with the above check.

[Another Reference](https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064)

Comment: Thanks. I used the above command. It emits some output but still trying to figure out how to interpret the messages.

Comment: @KarthikKrishnan If it gives you information like Serial Number, Issuer, Validity, Subject and that looks good and there are not errors or warnings, then it would be safe to say that the problem is not your certificate.